# statsd current time is two hours in the future--how to fix?

Tags: linux, statsd

When looking at our statsd data in graphite, the graphs are saying the current time is two hours in the future.  For instance, if we're looking at graphite at 9:00am, the graphs are telling us it's 11:00am.  The data lines up like it should--if we had 99 events at 9:00am, we can see the 99 events on the graphs at 11:00am.

The clock is correct on the host running statsd, and we tried stopping & starting the statsd process.  Any other suggestions on where to look to fix that?

Comment: Probably a `localtime` vs `gmtime` issue, or the hardware clock in local time, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by creating this file (since we're in California)

```
$ cat /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/local_settings.py

# Set your local timezone (django will *try* to figure this out automatically)
# If your graphs appear to be offset by a couple hours then this probably
# needs to be explicitly set to your local timezone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

Found the answer [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/183131)